# How to add Jackson annotations to POJO generated from XSD by JAXB/XJC?

Tags: json, jaxb, jersey, jackson

I'm generating POJOs from XSDs using JAXB. And I'm using Jersey/Jackson to serialize the POJOs to JSONs. For the whole project, I've created an ObjectMapper that has `Inclusion.NON_NULL` set. But for one particular serialization class, I want to include null values. I know, I have to use `Inclusion.ALWAYS` on the POJO to override the ObjectMapper, but the POJO I'm using is generated from XSDs.

Is there a way to add this Jackson's annotation `@JsonSerialize(include=Inclusion.ALWAYS)` to that one particular POJO during marshalling?

http://pastebin.com/a2Gvw19U

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to add one annotation, consider using my [JAXB2 Annotate Plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin). See, for instance, [this example](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin/tree/master/tests/issues), specifically [this bindings file](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin/blob/master/tests/issues/src/main/resources/binding.xjb).

In your case the bindings will look something like:

```
<jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='myPOJO']">
    <annox:annotate>
        @org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize
            (include=org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize.Inclusion.ALWAYS)
    </annox:annotate>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

(Not tested, just a sketch.)

Few hints:

- Syntax is Java, but you have to use fully qualified class names.
- Jackson JAR must be present in the XJC classpath, otherwise your annotations won't be found.

SO disclaimer: I am the author of the mentioned plugin.

Comment: Thanks. That's a cool plugin. Unfortunately, my security's team motto is, "let's be paranoid". I've to check if I could do some sorta preprocessing. I haven't gotten time to understand your code yet. I'll check that as well.

Comment: The plugin is completely open-source, everything is on GitHub.