# How to add include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL to @JsonSerialize using annox plugin

Tags: json, maven-jaxb2-plugin, annox, jaxb2-annotate-plugin

We are generating JAXB objects from xsd, using maven plugin maven-jaxb2-plugin. Below are dependencies we have

jaxb2-basics - 0.6.2

jaxb2-basics-annotate - 0.6.2

In our maven file, we also included -Xannotate and -XtoString

```
    <plugin>                
<groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                         <execution>
                            <id>exec1</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                                <bindingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd</bindingDirectory>
                                <generatePackage>org.learning.json.generated</generatePackage>
                                <generateDirectory>${basedir}/generated</generateDirectory>
                                <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                                <includeSchemas>
                                    <includeSchema>Person.xsd</includeSchema>
                                </includeSchemas>
                                <plugins>
                                    <plugin>
                                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                                        <version>0.6.2</version>
                                    </plugin>
                                    <plugin>
                                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                                        <version>0.6.2</version>
                                    </plugin>
                                </plugins>
                                <args>
                                    <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
                                    <arg>-XtoString</arg>
                                </args>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
```

The binding file is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
               xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
               xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
               jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc annox"
               jaxb:version="2.0">

     <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="Person.xsd" multiple="true">  
        <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='personType']/xs:sequence/xs:element[@type='xs:date']" multiple="true">
            <annox:annotate>
                <annox:annotate target="getter" annox:class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize" 
                                using="org.learning.json.JsonDateSerializer"/>
            </annox:annotate>
        </jaxb:bindings>
     </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

This did add @JsonSerialize(using=JsonDateSerializer.class). But I tried few options like below to add 
include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL, but did not work

```
<annox:annotate>
                <annox:annotate target="getter" annox:class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize" 
                                using="org.learning.json.JsonDateSerializer"
        include="org.codehause.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL"/>
            </annox:annotate> 



<annox:annotate>
                <annox:annotate target="getter" annox:class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize" 
                                using="org.learning.json.JsonDateSerializer"
        include="org.codehause.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize$Inclusion.NON_NULL"/>
            </annox:annotate>
```

But in all cases, getting ValueParseException. So what is the correct way of having parameters like include(), typing() of JsonSerialize be added to annotation.

Also, based on [How to add Jackson annotations to POJO generated from XSD by JAXB/XJC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227869/how-to-add-jackson-annotations-to-pojo-generated-from-xsd-by-jaxb-xjc) 
I also tried

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="Person.xsd" multiple="true">  
        <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='personType']/xs:sequence/xs:element[@type='xs:date']" multiple="true">
            <annox:annotate>
                <annox:annotate target="getter" annox:class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize" 
                                using="org.learning.json.JsonDateSerializer"/>
            </annox:annotate>
            <annox:annotate>
                    @org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize
                    (include=org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize.Inclusion.ALWAYS
            </annox:annotate>
        </jaxb:bindings>
     </jaxb:bindings>
```

This also did not add any include part in the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of the [`jaxb2-annotate-plugin`](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin).

First of all, try this for the XML syntax (which is deprecated starting from [1.0.0](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin/releases/tag/1.0.0)):

```
<annox:annotate
    target="getter"
    annox:class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize" 
    using="org.learning.json.JsonDateSerializer"
    include="NON_NULL"/>
```

Next, try this for the Java syntax:

```
<annox:annotate>
    @org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize
        (include=org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize.Inclusion.ALWAYS)
</annox:annotate>
```

The answer you linked to had a typo - the last `)` was missing. Maybe this is the problem, maybe not.

I think this should work. If it does not, please send me a pull request with a sample project in [tests](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin/tree/master/tests). I'll make it work.

**Note:** You'll have to use [`jaxb2-annotate-plugin`](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin) [1.0.0](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin/releases/tag/1.0.0) or later (the current is [1.0.1](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin/releases/tag/1.0.1)) for Java syntax to work.

Comment: The XML syntax you mentioned is working like a charm. Thank you once again.