# annotate all elements of a data type using maven-jaxb2-plugin

Tags: maven-jaxb2-plugin

My question is related to the following post.
[How to add Jackson annotations to POJO generated from XSD by JAXB/XJC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227869/how-to-add-jackson-annotations-to-pojo-generated-from-xsd-by-jaxb-xjc) 
Is there a way to add annotations using maven-jaxb2-plugin for all elements of a specific data type using bindings file? For example, annotate all 'xs:time' type elements with @JsonFormat annotation instead of adding annotation to each specific element separately.

Comment: Use `jaxb:bindings` with an XPath which selects all such element. Also add `multiple="true"` to `jaxb:bindings`.

Comment: It worked. Thank you.

Comment: Please answer your own question and show how it worked. This will help future readers (and you'll get some rep points).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks lexicore. The following addition in bindings file did the trick.

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="Schema.xsd" node="//xs:element[@type='xs:date']" multiple="true">
    <annox:annotate target="field">@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd", timezone="GMT")</annox:annotate>       
</jaxb:bindings>
```

The Xpath selects all the 'date' elements and we can annotate them with a single line.